# Catching an error in Python using function

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup

I would like to catch errors from BeautifulSoup, if there is no element. At the moment I am using the usual method:

```
try:
    var1 = soup.div.text
except AttributeError:
    var1 = 'N/A'
```

However, I am having to repeat this quite a lot at the moment and therefore wondering if its possible to write a custom function to do this, which I can reuse. For example:

```
def customerrorcatcher(something):
        ....
        ....


customerrorcatcher(soup.div.text)
```

Comment: You can pass a lambda to the function `customerrorcatcher(lambda: soup.div.text)`. Also what do you want to do when you handle the error?

Comment: `However, I am having to repeat this quite a lot at the moment`, What, where, and why?

Comment: @user202729, I would like to return 'N/A' string, assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
def get_attribute(obj, attr, default=None, on_error=None):
    try:
        return getattr(obj, attr)
    except AttributeError as e:
        if on_error: on_error(e)
        return default
```

And then you'd call it like:

```
text = get_attribute(soup.div, 'text', default='default_text', on_error=_logger.error)
```

You can even nest the calls:

```
text = get_attribute(get_attribute(soup, 'div'), 'text', default='default_text', on_error=_logger.error)
```